# EGit Eclipse: git commit moves the folder from var/www to git repository

Tags: git, egit

There was no problem while I was developing in Java EE Platform, and commiting. But in PHP my project folder needs to be in var/www else the server won't run the project. But whenever I commit my project, all the source code are moved to the git repository & eclipse also start editing those codes in repository.

Now I need to copy/paste the entire project to var/www from the repos, in order to execute and check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple & easy.

Just "Check the option" : Use or create repository in parent folder of project

And the rest of thing is done. BUT, I still don't understand one thing, why couldn't I change the working directory of the git repository. It's set default to the repository folder. Hope I get some answer from this. Thank You!